# Three js memory leak on CubeTextureLoader .load

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am developing a simple web app with three js and struggling with memory leak problem that I reproduce in Firefox but not in Chrome. In mobile browser is reproduced again.

My script creates a renderer (WebGlRenderer) an scene and a Perspective camera. Then I create a CubeTexture loader which I use to load the images of the a cube mesh (global var) and I add it to the scene.

I have a slider in order to navigate withing scenes. In each navigation (slider item click) I call the loader.load function passing to it the urls of the images of the new cube to load. Inside it I just only create a material and I update the cube mesh material.

Example of the script:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth /     window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);

// Cube mesh. The material of this mesh will be updated every time users clicks an item of slider
var cubeMesh = null;

var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();

// This function is called when users clicks an slider item. Here there is something making the memory grow on every call
function onSliderItemClick(urls) {

    skyCube = loader.load(
            urls,
            // On texture created
            function (texture) {
                var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
                    shader.uniforms["tCube"].value = texture;

                    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                        fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
                            vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
                            uniforms: shader.uniforms,
                            depthWrite: false,
                            side: THREE.BackSide

                    });
                    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
                    if (!cubeMesh) {
                        cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                            cubeMesh.position.set(0, controls.userHeight, 0);
                            // Add the inital cube mesh to the scene. Next imes this cube is already
                            // on the scene so we only update its material
                            scene.add(cubeMesh);
                    } else {
                            // We update the material of the cube mesh. Here memory increases. Old material still in memory?
                            cubeMesh.material = material;
                    }


            },
            // When loading
            function (xhr) {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
            },
        // On error
        function (xhr) {
        console.log('An error happened');
            }
      );
```

}

Every time I call the loader.load function and I update the material of the cube mesh the memory usage increases as constant. Finally when I have updated the material several times (clicking on slider items several times) then the memory usage is so hight that the O.S directly closes Firefox.

Any ideas on what could I do, see or try in order to update the material of the cube mesh being sure that non wanted objects are cleaned from memory?

Thanks a lot